CastError: Cast to string failed for value when using Angular ngx-editor
I'm using Angular17. It saves data successfully when using the code below:
<textarea [(ngModel)]="brand.promoMaterial" name="promoMaterial" id="promoMaterial"></textarea>

Please note that brand.promoMaterial is a string:
const BrandSchema = new Schema({
  brandDate:{
    type: Date
  },
  promoMaterial:{
    type:String
  }
})

However, when I use ngx-editor using the code below:
<div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
  <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="promoMaterial" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>
  <ngx-editor [editor]="promoMaterial" [(ngModel)]="brand.promoMaterial" [disabled]="false" [placeholder]="'Type here...'"></ngx-editor>
</div>

I get this 500 error:
{
    "status": "failed",
    "error": {
        "message": "Cast to string failed for value \"{\n  type: 'doc',\n  content: [ { type: 'paragraph', attrs: [Object], content: [Array] } ]\n}\" (type Object) at path \"promoMaterial\"",
        "stack": "CastError: Cast to string failed for value \"{\n  type: 'doc',\n  content: [ { type: 'paragraph', attrs: [Object], content: [Array] } ]\n}\" (type Object) at path \"promoMaterial\"\n    at model.Query.exec (/home/app/node-board/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4921:21)\n    at Query.then (/home/app/node-board/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:5020:15)"
    }
}

My TS file:
import { Editor, Toolbar, toHTML, toDoc} from 'ngx-editor';
export class brandComponent implements OnInit{
  toolbar: Toolbar = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['ordered_list', 'bullet_list'],
  ];
  public brand = {} as Brand;
  public promoMaterial = new Editor();
  constructor(
    private coreService: CoreService,
  ){
  }
}

What could be the possible reason? It saves the data when I don't use the editor.
